# JavaFX performance with nested panes

Tags: javafx

With custom controls and more complex GUIs, one usually ends up with a bunch of nested panes. Esp. with SceneBuilder its very easy to put together such a design. Are there any performance implications I should be aware of associated with this approach esp when some of these controls will be used in a TableView with a lot of rows (~1000) and lots of updates?

From my days working in Adobe Flex, this approach was frowned upon and could lead to sluggish GUIs.

Answer (score 0):

No, there aren't. Java FX is better than Swing in that regard.

However, the first thing you should do - if you have concerns like that - is to invest a few hours and create a simple prototype. JavaFX is perfect for RAD. Then you'll see. Nobody can possibly guess what your goal is when you say *"TableView with a lot of rows (~1000) and lots of updates"*.

Comment: The question is badly worded, but the [`Cell` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html) explains why `TableView`s with a large number of rows (potentially much more than 1000) are not a performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is not a problem usually, it always makes sense to optimize your UI.

**Proper use of JavaFX layout panes helps. Specifically, take a look at [GridPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html).**